# How do I do timed page refresh in Clojurescript with Reagent?

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I'm writing a Clojurescript SPA which needs to regularly (maybe once every 30 seconds, maybe once a minute) poll a server and get some updated data.

How should I do this in Clojurescript with Reagent (the React framework)?

Do I just use Javascript's low-level setTimeout() or is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Clojurescript / React?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Reagent examples](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/examples/simple/src/simpleexample/core.cljs#L8) show this well:

```
(ns simpleexample.core
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]))

(defonce timer (r/atom (js/Date.)))

(defonce time-color (r/atom "#f34"))

(defonce time-updater (js/setInterval
                       #(reset! timer (js/Date.)) 1000))
```

The first example [in the re-frame docs](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/examples/simple/src/simple/core.cljs) is similar:

```
;; -- Domino 1 - Event Dispatch -----------------------------------------------

(defn dispatch-timer-event
  []
  (let [now (js/Date.)]
    (rf/dispatch [:timer now])))  ;; <-- dispatch used

;; Call the dispatching function every second.
;; `defonce` is like `def` but it ensures only one instance is ever
;; created in the face of figwheel hot-reloading of this file.
(defonce do-timer (js/setInterval dispatch-timer-event 1000))
```

As with Clojure, in many instances we reuse existing machinery from the host platform without disguising it with a wrapper (or reinventing it with new code).